# Prevent xml bomb XercesDOMParser - C++

Tags: c++, dom, xerces

I am using XercesDOMParser to read an xml file in linux (c++), I want to prevent xml bomb (Billion laughs) so I set these properties:

```
parser->setDoNamespaces(true)
parser->setDisableDefaultEntityResolution(true)
parser->setEntityResolver(NULL)
parser->setSkipDTDValidation(true)
```

However, it doesn't help and bomb still remain.
Do you know how to prevent it (I have to use xerces with DOM only)

10x!

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to prevent entity expansion, and thus prevent the billion laughs attack.  This is because billion laughs attacks can be well-formed XML, and `XercesDOMParser` is a pretty strict implementation of DOM.  However, you can prevent the billion laughs attack in Xerces by adding a `SecurityManager`.

```
SecurityManager sm;
sm.setEntityExpansionLimit(100);

parser->setSecurityManager(&sm);
```

If you add that to your code, Xerces will throw a `SAXParseException` when the parser has expanded more than the number of Entities you set, in this case 100.  This will prevent the billion laughs.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to suppress the use of Entities altogether you can implement overrides on the DefaultHandler.   In the declaration:

```
class MyHandler: public Xerces::DefaultHandler
{
   <...>
    void internalEntityDecl(
        const XMLCh* const name,
        const XMLCh* const value) override;


    void externalEntityDecl(
        const XMLCh* const name,
        const XMLCh* const publicId,
        const XMLCh* const systemId) override;
}
```

and in the definition:

```
void
XercesXMLHandler::internalEntityDecl(
    const XMLCh* const name,
    const XMLCh* const value )
{
    FailBecauseEntity( name );
}

void
XercesXMLHandler::externalEntityDecl(
    const XMLCh* const name,
    const XMLCh* const publicId,
    const XMLCh* const systemId )
{
    FailBecauseEntity( name );
}
```